# Cannot read property 'getMonetizationServiceClient' of undefined Alexa SDK

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to add In Skill Purchasing to my Alexa skill with the following code:

```
const LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === "LaunchRequest";
    },
    handle(handlerInput){
        console.log("In LaunchRequest");

    const locale = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.locale;
    const ms = handlerInput.serviceClientFactory.getMonetizationServiceClient();

    return ms.getInSkillProducts(locale).then(function(result) {
      // Code to handle result.inSkillProducts goes here
       const totalProducts = result.inSkillProducts.length;
       const purchasableProducts = result.inSkillProducts.filter(record => record.purchasable == 'PURCHASABLE');
       const entitledProducts = result.inSkillProducts.filter(record => record.entitled == 'ENTITLED');

       return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak('Found total ' + result.inSkillProducts.length + ' products of which ' + purchasableProducts.length + ' are purchasable and ' + entitledProducts.length + ' are entitled.')
        .getResponse();
    });
    },
};
```

When I run the code, I get the following error message:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'getMonetizationServiceClient' of undefined",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Object.handle (/var/task/index.js:16:50)",
    "GenericHandlerAdapter.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/ask-sdk-runtime/dist/dispatcher/request/handler/GenericHandlerAdapter.js:63:47)",
    "step (/var/task/node_modules/ask-sdk-runtime/dist/dispatcher/request/handler/GenericHandlerAdapter.js:44:23)",
    "Object.next (/var/task/node_modules/ask-sdk-runtime/dist/dispatcher/request/handler/GenericHandlerAdapter.js:25:53)",
    "/var/task/node_modules/ask-sdk-runtime/dist/dispatcher/request/handler/GenericHandlerAdapter.js:19:71",
    "new Promise (<anonymous>)",
    "__awaiter (/var/task/node_modules/ask-sdk-runtime/dist/dispatcher/request/handler/GenericHandlerAdapter.js:15:12)",
    "GenericHandlerAdapter.execute (/var/task/node_modules/ask-sdk-runtime/dist/dispatcher/request/handler/GenericHandlerAdapter.js:61:16)",
    "GenericRequestDispatcher.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/ask-sdk-runtime/dist/dispatcher/GenericRequestDispatcher.js:173:58)",
    "step (/var/task/node_modules/ask-sdk-runtime/dist/dispatcher/GenericRequestDispatcher.js:44:23)"
  ]
}
```

I have used the code from the Alexa SDK site which can be found here: https://ask-sdk-for-nodejs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Calling-Alexa-Service-APIs.html#getinskillproducts. Can somebody please tell me what is going wrong or how I can fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you share your exports section I may be able to help further. If you are using the custom alexa skill builder with the following code:

```
const skillBuilder = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom();
exports.handler = skillBuilder
.addRequestHandlers()
```

or

```
exports.handler = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
.addRequestHandlers()
```

then you will just need to add 
`.withApiClient(new Alexa.DefaultApiClient())`

For example your exports may look like this:

```
const skillBuilder = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom();
exports.handler = skillBuilder
  .addRequestHandlers(
    CancelResponseHandler,
    LaunchRequestHandler,
    HelloWorldIntentHandler,
    HelpIntentHandler,
    CancelAndStopIntentHandler,
    SessionEndedRequestHandler
  )
  .addErrorHandlers(ErrorHandler)
  .withApiClient(new Alexa.DefaultApiClient())
  .lambda();`
```

I found this solution from the following issue: https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/issues/356